# clang-cl doesn't allow operator-overloads for __m128 because it's not a class or enum? Workaround to make it like MSVC?

Tags: c++, clang, operator-overloading, intrinsics, clang-cl

The following code builds just fine under `cl`, but fails under `clang-cl`:

```cpp
#define NUDGE_FORCEINLINE __forceinline

NUDGE_FORCEINLINE __m128 operator-(__m128 a) {
  return _mm_xor_ps(a, _mm_set1_ps(-0.0f));
}
```

This is the error message:

```
..\nudge.cpp(65,26): error: overloaded 'operator-' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type
NUDGE_FORCEINLINE __m128 operator-(__m128 a) {
                         ^
```

The code is from [rasmusbarr/nudge](https://github.com/rasmusbarr/nudge/blob/master/nudge.cpp), an experiment which seems to be abandoned since 2017.

Setup (CMake/VSCode):

- `cl` with `VS Build Tools 2019 v16.8.2`
- `clang-cl` with `C++ Clang Tools for Windows 10.0.0 (VS Build Tools 2019 v16.8.2)`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
project(nudge LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_executable(tests "nudge.cpp" "tests/main.cpp")
target_include_directories(tests PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Research:

I came across these two sources ([1](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/issues/50), [2](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2018-July/066554.html)) that seem to point out that the reason might be *clang-cl does not consider __m128 to be a struct type*. They fixed it in ([1](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/issues/50)), but it seems that they just disable SSE for some platforms.

Although it was a long shot, I tried compiling with the VS version of `immintrin.h` and `intrin.h` but that path led nowhere.

I also noticed that someone else who build this experiment [used the c++11 standard](https://github.com/xdrie/nudge-d/blob/master/lib/nudge/meson.build) so I tried that too by setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` in cmake. No change.

**Question:**

How can I modify the code (or change compiler flags) in order to build [rasmusbarr/nudge](https://github.com/rasmusbarr/nudge/blob/master/nudge.cpp) with clang-cl?

Thank you

Comment: Normal clang allows function overloads that only differ by `__m128i` vs. `__m128d` or a `long long` arg.  https://godbolt.org/z/b7eYE8.  Oh, but apparently operator overloads are different.  https://godbolt.org/z/GPc6Po.  You could use one of the other C++ wrapper libraries, like VCL, or maybe use a class wrapper for `__m128` instead of `__m128` directly, perhaps using a C preprocessor macro as a hack for existing code.

Comment: How would a wrapper class for `__m128` look like?

Comment: Clang already provides `operator-(__m128)`, which does exactly what you want: https://godbolt.org/z/c75fWf

Comment: I've disabled all the operator overload code and it seems to build and run fine. I'll test the rest of the operators with godbolt.